# Is there a top like tool that shows processes and ports, live?

Tags: linux, port, process, top

I'd like to be monitoring ports in "realtime" and the processes that use them. Is there any tool that can handle that?
I imagine somethinkg like top, but with a column that lists all ports the process is using... or a list of ports, protocol, and the process that has that port open or is listenting to.

This is for Linux based OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I found `nethogs`, it's right what I needed in the first place:

It needs the device name as the first parameter, and must be run as sudo:
`sudo nethogs wlp9s0`

Answer (score 5):

Was just going to ask which OS and noticed that you edited to add that.  You're in luck then.  Try this quick and dirty one-liner (as root) in a BASH shell:

```
while true ; do output=$(netstat -anptu) ; clear ; echo "$output" ; sleep 2 ; done
```

edit: More concise, ordered output:

```
while true ; do output=$( (netstat -anpt | awk '{ print $1" "$4" "$7" "$6 }' | tail -n +3 ; netstat -anpu | awk '{ print $1" "$4" "$6 }' | tail -n +3 ) | egrep '[0-9]\/' | sort | uniq) ; clear ; date ; echo "$output" ; sleep 2 ; done
```

Comment: This is great! I prefer this approach as I can customize it to whatever needs I have, thank you!

Comment: You can use the "watch" command in place of the wile loop.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify an OS. But if it is Linux (which I guess is likely, since you mention `top`), then there exist a tool called `iftop`, which can display the current bandwidth usage by IP address. This is not exactly what you asked for, but depending on your needs, might be close enough.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it's for Linux, I've just edited the question to make it clear. I've seen that you can enable source and destination ports pressing capital S, and D. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to show the process too?

Comment: @LuisLoboBorobia You could try `watch 'netstat -ntlp'` or variants of that.

Comment: Thanks, that one is useful too. I prefer Joshua's answer though, as I can customize it. Thanks anyway! your answers were great too.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't anyone suggest the `-c` option for `netstat`.

Add `-c` to your existing `netstat` command & it would show you the output live.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `-i` and `-p` options of [lsof](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) tool:

`watch lsof -a -itcp -p <PID>`